# php script was working, now second $_POST suddenly not working

Tags: php, html

I am fairly new to `php` and have been searching for three days to find my problem. The script below worked for two years, and now suddenly the second `POST` command never populates (it is the last lines of code, and when I echo `$_POST['input'];` nothing is ever there.) I have looked at `var_dump$[_$POST]` and it gets `$formType`, but never `$input`.

Why would this suddenly stop working? It goes to the next form, but nothing works because it all counts on `$input` being passed on.

I am running on a unix server, Network Solutions.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

here is the code (sanitized names of directories and databases, obviously):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['auth'] != "yes") {
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['Enter'])) {
        header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/subdirectory/nextform.php");
    } else if (isset($_REQUEST['Delete'])) {
        header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/subdirectory/deleterow.php");
    }
    ########################################
    ####checks what kind of service request######
    #########################################

?>

<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php
echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>"> 
<p><legend>Form Type</legend></p>
<p> <basefont size = "4"></p>
<p><label for="formType" required>*Select Type of Form:</label></p>
<p><select name="formType"></p>
<p><option value="">select</option></p>
<p><option value="Garda">Security Officer</option></p>
<p><option value="Surveil">Surveil</option></p>
<p><option value="EmployApp">Employment Application</option></p>
<p></select></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form> 
    <?php

    $formType = $_POST['formType'];

    SESSION_register("formType");


    if ($formType == Garda) {

        // Connects to your Database 
        include("introGardaform.php");
        $database = "Gardaform"; // provide your database name 
        $db_table = "GardaINQ"; // leave this as is 

        $db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
        mysql_select_db($database, $db);

        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GardaINQ") or die(mysql_error());

        // puts the "GardaINQ"database table info into the $info array 
        //$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ); 

        Print "<table border cellpadding=15>";
        while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
            Print "<tr>";
            Print "<th>Inquiry Number:</th> <td>" . $info['Inquiry_num'] . "</td> ";
            Print "<th>Contact Name:</th> <td>" . $info['contactName'] . " </td>";
            Print "<th>Contact Number:</th> <td>" . $info['contactNum'] . " </td></tr>";
        }
        Print "</table>";
    }

    if ($formType == Surveil) {

        // Connects to your Database 
        include("investfm.php");
        $database = "investigateform"; // provide your database name 
        $db_table = "surveil"; // leave this as is 

        $db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
        mysql_select_db($database, $db);

        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM surveil") or die(mysql_error());

        // puts the "surveil"database table info into the $info array 
        //$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ); 

        Print "<table border cellpadding=15>";
        while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
            Print "<tr>";
            Print "<th>Inquiry Number:</th> <td>" . $info['Inquiry_num'] . "</td> ";
            Print "<th>Contact Name:</th> <td>" . $info['contactName'] . " </td>";
            Print "<th>Contact Number:</th> <td>" . $info['contactNum'] . " </td></tr>";
        }
        Print "</table>";
    }

    if ($formType == EmployApp) {

        // Connects to your Database 
        include("introhires.php");
        $database = "hires"; // provide your database name 
        $db_table = "hiresentry"; // leave this as is 

        $db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
        mysql_select_db($database, $db);

        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hiresentry") or die(mysql_error());

        // puts the "hiresentry"database table info into the $info array 
        //$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ); 

        Print "<table border cellpadding=15>";
        while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
            Print "<tr>";
            Print "<th>First Name:</th> <td>" . $info['firstName'] . " </td>";
            Print "<th>Last Name:</th> <td>" . $info['lastName'] . " </td>";
            Print "<th>Date:</th> <td>" . $info['date'] . " </td></tr>";
        }
        Print "</table>";
    }

?>

<form name="finddata" method="POST" action="<?php
echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>"> 
<p> <basefont size = "4"></p>
<p><label for="finddata" required>Enter Inquiry Number for Garda or Surveil, Last name for Employment 

Application:</label></p>
<p><input type = "text" size="20" maxlength="40" required onKeyPress="return noenter()" 

name="input"></p>
<p><input type="hidden" value="<?php
echo $formType;
?>" name="formType"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="Enter" value="Enter" ></p><br/>
<p><input type="submit" style="font-face: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: larger; color: red; background-color: #FFFFC0; border: 3pt ridge lightgrey"   name = "Delete" value="Delete"></p>
</form> 

<?php

    $input = $_POST['input'];
    SESSION_register("input");
    echo $_POST['input'];

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have used `SESSION_register("formType");` undefined function and This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

So you can use `$_SESSION["formType"]=$formType;`, also

Need to wrap `"` or `'` to check the string. Try this,

```
if($formType=="Garda"){
```

and `if($formType=="EmployApp"){`

instead of

```
if($formType==Garda){

if($formType==EmployApp){
```

Comment: PHP automatically turns unquoted tokens like this into strings, so it shouldn't cause the script to fail. It might causes a warning, that's it.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I changed the SESSIONS as you mentioned, and added the double quotes, but still get only the formType in POST...I never get the input in POST.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of issues on your code.

- You are comparing your `$formtype` variable to a constant instead. It has to be like this. `if($formType=="Garda"){` and `if($formType=="Surveil"){` and `if($formType=="EmployApp"){` add the double quotes to all those `if` statements as shown.
- You are using a deprecated version i.e. `session_register`

Comment: Thank you. I know my code is not pretty but it did work for 2 years. Made the updates, still don't get input to POST

Answer (score 1):

can you try the following:

1. Remove the action attribute completely from both the forms as by default it is POST to self.
2. replace the font-face css property to font-family property in the last element of the second form. however that should not be the cause of the issue you are facing.
3. As there are 2 forms in the page and there are 2 code blocks depending on the form post, I assume that your second form post creates the issue in the first part of the code as the data for the first from will not be posted from the submit button in the second form. so before executing the piece of code you should identify if that piece of code should be executed or not. A simple multi form setup should look something like this:

```php
     <form name="form1" method="post">
         <input type="text"/>
         <input type="submit" name="form1-submit" value="Submit Name" />
     </form>

     <!-- form1 specific code -->
     <?php
         if(isset($_POST["form1-submit"]))
         {
             // do your stuff here
         }
     ?>

     <form name="form2" method="post">
         <input type="text"/>
         <input type="submit" name="form2-submit" value="Submit Name" />
     </form>

     <!-- form2 specific code -->
     <?php
         if(isset($_POST["form2-submit"]))
         {
             // do your stuff here
         }
     ?>

     <!-- independent code -->
     <?php
         // do your common code here.
     ?>
```

If you can write the code in above manner you will be able to resolve your problem yourself. please let us know in case above helped.

Comment: I tried these updates, but I still don't get "form2-submit"to post... the first form1submit figures out which database to open and show to the user. the second one selects which line of the database the user wants, and sends it on to another script to format and print it. that other script is called out in the header. for some reason, the data the user types in never seems to get posted.

Comment: OK. I missed something first time through. Now I get both variables to post and echo, but to get this to work I had to move the page redirect from top to bottom. If I leave it at the top, it redirects when I hit Enter and the POST variables don't carry. If I put it at the bottom, there is already php output and header doesn' t work. Sorry to be so illiterate about this!

Comment: Finally got it to work! Thanks to all for input. I had to add this is the last php section:$input = $_POST['input'];
$_SESSION["input"]=$input;

$formType = $_POST['formType'];
$_SESSION["formType"]=$formType;  plus in the script to which it redirects, I had to add at the very top these two lines  $formType = $_SESSION["formType"];    
$input = $_SESSION["input"];              Maybe it is a Network Solutions thing, or perhaps a change in php. Thank you for taking the time to educate me on the updates and the structure!!